# How can I add a webpack bundled nodejs express app to a wordpress page?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, wordpress, express, webpack

I have a full stack app with React on the frontend built in a nodejs/express backend. I used webpack to bundle the app and it can be viewed at localhost:3000 when i run the command `node server.bundle.js` in the terminal. I have been trying to get the app to display in a wordpress page template by adding the script `<script src="/dist/server.bundle.js"></script>`, but have been unsuccessful. Please help point me in the right direction.

### Server.js

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import App from "./client/app.js";

function handleRender(req, res) {
    const reactHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);
    const htmlTemplate = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Universal React server bundle</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">${reactHtml}</div>
        <script src="public/client.bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>`;
    res.send(htmlTemplate);
}


const app = express();

app.use("/public", express.static("./public"));

app.get("*", handleRender);
app.listen(3000);
console.log("App is running on http://localhost:3000");
```

### Webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');


const clientConfig = {
    entry: './client/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'public/client.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};

const serverConfig = {
    entry: './server.js',
    target: "node",
    devtool: "source-map",
    externals: [nodeExternals(), {
      "react": "React",
      "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'server.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.BannerPlugin({
            banner: 'require("source-map-support").install();',
            raw: true,
            entryOnly: false
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = [clientConfig, serverConfig];
```

### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "twentynineteen",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Creating a server bundle with webpack",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/WordPress/twentynineteen/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/WordPress/twentynineteen#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wordpress/browserslist-config": "^2.5.0",
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^9.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "chokidar-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "rtlcss": "^2.4.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.14",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.5.4"
  },
    "map": false
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "extends @wordpress/browserslist-config"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build",
    "start": "wp-scripts start",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "watch": "chokidar \"**/*.scss\" -c \"npm run build\" --initial"
  }
}
```

### functions.php

```
// Enqueue Theme JS w React Dependency
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueued_bundled_theme_js' );
function my_enqueued_bundled_theme_js() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'my-theme-frontend',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/server.bundle.js',
    ['wp-element'],
    time(), // Change this to null for production
    true
  );
}
```

Comment: does `server.bundle.js` run? what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes `server.bundle.js` does run in development on localhost:3000. it shows the full app. I just can't get the app to display on a wordpress page.

Comment: Got any success ?